# How to adapt datatables example "multi-filter" for multi-table support

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, fnfilter

After successfully implementing [datatables multi-filter](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter.html) to my system for one table, I'd like to implement it for all of my tables, which are organized by several tabs, like [shown here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/tabs_and_scrolling.html).

To reach that, I think I have to set three individual variables:

```
var oTable0 = $('#tabs-0 table.display').dataTable({
var oTable1 = $('#tabs-1 table.display').dataTable({
var oTable2 = $('#tabs-2 table.display').dataTable({
```

For filtering, I should need something like:

```
$("tfoot input").keyup( function () {
/* Filter on the column (the index) of this element */
  oTable0.fnFilter( this.value, $("tfoot input").index(this) );
  oTable1.fnFilter( this.value, $("tfoot input").index(this) );
  oTable2.fnFilter( this.value, $("tfoot input").index(this) );
});
```

For the table footers I also have to individualize the rows. Here an example for the first table:

```
<th>
  <input type="text" name="search_tabs0_rfid" value="Search column" class="search_init0" />
</th>
<th>
  <input type="text" name="search_tabs0_art" value="Search column" class="search_init0" />
</th>
...
```

For adapting the user friendlyness part I thought of:

```
$("tfoot input").each( function (i) {
    asInitVals0[i] = this.value;
    asInitVals1[i] = this.value;
    asInitVals2[i] = this.value;
});

$("tfoot input").focus( function () {
    if ( this.className == "search_init0" ){ this.className = ""; this.value = "";}
    if ( this.className == "search_init1" ){ this.className = ""; this.value = "";}
    if ( this.className == "search_init2" ){ this.className = ""; this.value = "";}
});

$("tfoot input").blur( function (i) {
    if ( this.value == "" ){ this.className = "search_init0"; this.value = asInitVals0[$("tfoot input").index(this)];}
    if ( this.value == "" ){ this.className = "search_init1"; this.value = asInitVals1[$("tfoot input").index(this)];}
    if ( this.value == "" ){ this.className = "search_init2"; this.value = asInitVals2[$("tfoot input").index(this)];}
});
```

Now, the first Tab (#tabs-0) is working fine, but the rest is not.

Maybe the part

```
$("tfoot input")
```

Is a problem because this occurs in every one of the three individual tables.

So, how can I get these column searches bound to their specified table? Which part did I miss?

Cheers,
thowi

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to isolate instances start from an ancestor element that isolates only the instance elements needed  which I think could be `tfoot` in your case.

```
$("tfoot input").blur( function (i) {
    /* traverse up the document tree to ancestor needed*/
    var $parent=$(this).closest('tfoot');
    /* index only the inputs in current parent tfoot*/
    var index=$parent.find('input').index(this);
    /* more code*/
});
```

If you needed to interact with the `dataTables` API...can look up to the table itself and do something like:

```
$parent.closest('table').datatables_API_method()
```

Comment: Hi charlie. Thank you for your quick response! I'm sorry I have to say that I'm not really familiar with JS and also with the datatables API. So I have my problems following your advice and adapting my code like you suggested. Where should I use the new variables $parent and index and how do they affect the part `$("tfoot input").each( function (i) {`?

Comment: So, after trying your code for a while I checked with `alert(index);` how the index is changing when klicking the input fields. I thought I could add something like `if ( this.value == "" && index == 1){ this.className = "search_init0"` so this case will only be affected when a special index is active. The thing is: the index is changing on every box klick of one table. So I think I need an index change for every single table. My tables are organized outside the javascript in html divs - so I can't fetch this data in the javascript right? Any other thoughts what might help?

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net. Can use CDN resources for dataTables plugin and css